# Clear text from JLabel when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, timer, transactions

I have completed my assignment, that is meant to simulate(using a timer) a series of random transactions occuring via two different types of accounts (Current or Savings). I have the program working, except there is one little thing that I have attempted to correct, but cannot get to work.

I have a JLabel, which shows the output of what transactions were randomly attempted, when the simulation is started. The only problem is, when I select a different account, such as Current instead of Savings, and start simulation, the other account transaction data still shows up when the other accounts random transactions are taking place.

What I would like is that when I have simulated the current account, and the JLabel has been populated with transaction data, that when I click savings account and start simulation that the transaction data from the current account will be cleared, so that only the new Savings transaction will be stored.

I have tried to use tran.setText(""); to clear the data but the old transaction data was still there. I also created a button on another revision of the code, and coded the button to tran.setText(""); when the button was clicked it did clear the data, but when I started the simulation for the other account the old data appeared again.

I am thinking maybe something has to be added or changed in the timer's code?

Thanks for any sugesstions people may have.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author wafa
 */
public class Container extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form Container
 */
float total_balance = 0;
String transaction = "";
float thisMonth = 0;
 float savingWithdrawChance = 2;
 int depositBonus = 1;
 int isSimulating = 0;
 int iscreated = 0;



 Timer  timer ;//= new Timer();
    public Container() {

    initComponents();
    isCreated.setVisible(false);
    withdrawButton.setVisible(false);
    depositButton.setVisible(false);
    dispMonth.setVisible(false);
    dispYear.setVisible(false);
    chances.setVisible(false);
    depositField.setVisible(false);
    withdrawField.setVisible(false);
 //   total.setText(Float.toString(total_balance)+" £");
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    initial = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    create = new javax.swing.JButton();
    start = new javax.swing.JButton();
    stop = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tran = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    total = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    isCreated = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    withdrawField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    depositField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    withdrawButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    depositButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    dispMonth = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    dispYear = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    chances = new javax.swing.JLabel();


    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Current", "Saving" }));
    jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setText("AccountType");

    initial.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            initialActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Initial Balance");

    create.setText("Create Account");
    create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            createActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    start.setText("Start Simulating");
    start.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            startActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    stop.setText("Stop Simulating");
    stop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            stopActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    tran.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TRAILING);
    tran.setText("Transactions");
    tran.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);
    tran.setIconTextGap(20);
    tran.setVerticalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 344, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(tran, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 355, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(22, 22, 22))
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(initial, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(create))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(start, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                    .addComponent(stop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 131, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(60, 60, 60)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(initial)
                    .addComponent(create))
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(57, 57, 57)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(start, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(stop, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 87, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(tran, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 222, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jLabel3.setText("Total Balance");

    total.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    total.setText("   ");

    isCreated.setText("Account Created");

    withdrawButton.setText("Withdraw");
    withdrawButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            withdrawButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    depositButton.setText("Deposit");
    depositButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            depositButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    dispMonth.setText("Months");

    dispYear.setText("Year");



    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addGap(80, 80, 80)
                            .addComponent(total, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 63, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(dispYear)
                                .addComponent(dispMonth)
                                .addComponent(tran2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 341, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(120, 120, 120)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(isCreated)
                        .addComponent(depositField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 122, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(withdrawField))))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(withdrawButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(depositButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGap(79, 79, 79))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(chances, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 72, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(97, 97, 97))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addComponent(isCreated)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(total))
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addComponent(chances, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(withdrawField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(withdrawButton))
            .addGap(25, 25, 25)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(depositField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(depositButton))
            .addGap(39, 39, 39)
            .addComponent(dispMonth)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(dispYear)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(tran2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 216, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    total.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleName("total_bal");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 330, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 391, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void initialActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       
float months = 0;
 float year = 0;
    Random ran = new Random();
    int isWhat = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    int overDrawn = 0;
private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
     if(iscreated == 1)
         {      
    timer = new Timer();

             //    withdrawButton.setVisible(true);
               //  depositButton.setVisible(true);

               isSimulating = 1;
    try{
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

          dispMonth.setVisible(true);
          dispYear.setVisible(true);

            months++;
            amount = ran.nextInt((int)total_balance+ran.nextInt(300));
            isWhat = ran.nextInt(2);
            System.out.println(amount+"-----"+isWhat);
           if(isWhat == 1)
           {
                  Object selectedItem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
   if(selectedItem.toString().matches("Current") && iscreated==1){
    thisMonth += amount ;
    if(thisMonth>=500 && depositBonus == 1)
    {
        if(iscreated==1){
        depositBonus = 0;
    total_balance = total_balance +10+ amount;
        }

    }
    else
    {
           if(iscreated==1){
        total_balance = total_balance + amount;
           }
    }

   }
   else
   {
       if(iscreated==1)
      total_balance = total_balance + amount;

   }
   if(iscreated==1){
    total.setText(Float.toString(total_balance)+" £");

   transaction += "Deposit of " + amount+" £ ";
   tran.setText("<html>" + ""+transaction+"" + "<br><br></html>");

   }



           }
           else
           {
                 Object selectedItem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
   if(selectedItem.toString().matches("Current") && iscreated==1){
    if(true)
    {
        float entered =  amount;
        if( (total_balance+200)>=entered)
        {
               if(iscreated==1){
            total_balance -= amount;
               }
        }
        else
        {   if(iscreated==1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(create, "Overdraft exceeded");
             overDrawn = 1;
        }
        }
            if(iscreated==1){
         total.setText(Float.toString(total_balance)+" £");
            }
    }
   }
   else
   {
       float entered =  amount;
        if( (total_balance-entered)>=100 && savingWithdrawChance>0)
        {
            if(iscreated==1){
            total_balance -= amount;
            savingWithdrawChance--;
            chances.setText("Withdraw chances :"+Float.toString(savingWithdrawChance));
            }

        }
        else
        {
               if(iscreated==1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(create, "Withdraw could not occur, or you have exceed withdrawal chances");
             overDrawn= 1;
               }
        }

           if(iscreated==1){
         total.setText(Float.toString(total_balance)+" £");
           }

   }
      if(iscreated==1){
  if(overDrawn==1)
  {
      overDrawn = 0;
  }
  else{
   transaction += "Wtihdrawal of " + amount +" £     ";
tran.setText("<html>"+transaction+"<br><br></html>");


     withdrawButton.setVisible(false);
    depositButton.setVisible(false);
  }

      }

           }

            dispMonth.setText("Months "+Float.toString(months));
            dispYear.setText("Years "+Float.toString(year));
            //System.out.println(months);
            if(months==12)
            {
              // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(create, "Withdraw or deposit");
                depositBonus = 1;
               months=0;
               thisMonth = 0;
               year++;
            savingWithdrawChance= 2;
               if(total_balance>0)
               {
                      Object selectedItem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
                    if(selectedItem.toString().matches("Saving"))
                         total_balance = (float) (total_balance +  (total_balance* 0.03));
                    transaction += "Annual profit of  " + (total_balance* 0.03) +" £ Added";
                     tran.setText("<html>"+transaction+"<br><br></html>");

                  total.setText(Float.toString(total_balance)+" £");



               }
            }
         }
    }, 5*1000, 5*1000);
    create.setVisible(false);
    initial.setVisible(false);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("please restart applicaion");
    }
         }
     else
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(create, "Create Account First");
     }
}                                     

private void stopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        isSimulating = 0;
      create.setVisible(true);
      initial.setVisible(true);
      months = 0;
      year = 0;
      timer.cancel();
      timer.purge();
      withdrawButton.setVisible(false);
      depositButton.setVisible(false);



}                                    

private void createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Object selectedItem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
     iscreated = 1;
   if(selectedItem.toString().matches("Current"))
   {
       iscreated = 1;
       //System.out.prfloatln("---");
       if(!initial.getText().toString().matches(""))
       {
       float init = Float.parseFloat(initial.getText().toString());
            if(init>=1)
            {
                    total_balance = init;
                    isCreated.setText("Account created type : "+selectedItem.toString());
                     isCreated.setVisible(true);
                     total.setText(initial.getText().toString()+" £");
                  //  withdrawButton.setVisible(true);
                    // depositButton.setVisible(true);
                      initial.setText("");
                      thisMonth = total_balance;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Initial Balance must be at least £1");
            }
       }
   }

     if(selectedItem.toString().matches("Saving"))
   {
       //System.out.prfloatln("---");
       if(initial.getText().toString()!="")
       {
       float init = Float.parseFloat(initial.getText().toString());
            if(init>=100)
            {
                    total_balance = init;
                      isCreated.setText("Account created type : "+selectedItem.toString());
                     isCreated.setVisible(true);
                     total.setText(initial.getText().toString()+" £");
                    // withdrawButton.setVisible(true);
                     //depositButton.setVisible(true);
                     initial.setText("");
                     thisMonth = total_balance;
                      chances.setVisible(true);
                      chances.setText("Withdraw Chances :"+Float.toString(savingWithdrawChance));
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Inital Balance must be at least £100");
            }
       }
   }

}                                      

private void depositButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

}                                             

private void withdrawButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

}                                              

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (floatroduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Container.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Container.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Container.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Container.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Container().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel chances;
private javax.swing.JButton create;
private javax.swing.JButton depositButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField depositField;
private javax.swing.JLabel dispMonth;
private javax.swing.JLabel dispYear;
private javax.swing.JTextField initial;
private javax.swing.JLabel isCreated;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JButton start;
private javax.swing.JButton stop;
private javax.swing.JLabel total;
private javax.swing.JLabel tran;
private javax.swing.JLabel tran2;
private javax.swing.JButton withdrawButton;
private javax.swing.JTextField withdrawField;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
tran.setText(null);
```

I think that should work.